# Blazor - How to get layout @Body path?

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I am solving problem with breadcrumb navigation and dynamic showing (I want to avoid have in every razor component (one of Pages) static data. Thank you in forward.

**Problem: how to get path of the *@Body* component?** In the body is of course the one of (default folder name in project) Pages. So line 1 of "body itself" is @page "/somePage"...

My (shortened) layout:

```
<div class="page">
    <div class="main">
        <div class="top-row TitleButtonList @((closedLeftBar) ? "TitleButtonListClose" : "") ">
            <TitleButton />
        </div>
        <div class="top-row">
            <BreadcrumbNav breadCrumbData="breadCrumbDatas"></BreadcrumbNav>
            <p>Error test name: @path</p>
        </div>

        <div class="content px-4 @((closedLeftBar) ? "contentClose col-md-10" : "contentOpen col-md-9")">
            @Body
            <FOLButtons />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@code {
    public List<BreadCrumbData> breadCrumbDatas;
    string path = string.Empty;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        breadCrumbDatas = breadCrumbService.GetProperList();
        path = ??????
    }
}
```

Model of BreadCrumb:

```
public class BreadCrumbData
    {
        [Required]
        public string Text { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string URL { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int Level { get; set; }

        [Required]
            #nullable enable
        public string? ParentURL { get; set; }

        public BreadCrumbData(string text, string url, int level, string parentURL)
        {
            Text = text;
            URL = url;
            Level = level;
            ParentURL = parentURL;
        }
    }
```

Breadcrumb component (that one what is in layout)

```
<nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
    <ol class="breadcrumb">
        @if (breadCrumbData != null)
        {

            @foreach (var item in breadCrumbData)
            {
                @if (item == breadCrumbData.Last())
                {
                    <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">@item.Text</li>

                }
                else
                {
                    <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="@item.URL">@item.Text</a></li>
                }
            }
        }
    </ol>
</nav>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public List<BreadCrumbData> breadCrumbData { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Why enable nullable on `ParentURL`? Strings are already nullable.

Comment: It is simple - because when I wrote it I did not realized it. Of course this is working properly (at this time :) )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Blazor provides the `NavigationManager` for this purpose (see [Blazor routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-5.0#uri-and-navigation-state-helpers)):

```cs
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager;

protected override void OnInitialized()
{
    breadCrumbDatas = breadCrumbService.GetProperList();

    // Get everything after the domain + '/' (e.g. after "https://example.com/")
    path = NavigationManager.Uri.Substring(Navigator.BaseUri.Length); 

    // You can also listen for a path change by subscribing to 
    //     NavigationManager.LocationChanged.
}
```

---

A couple notes/suggestions:

- Since `NavigationManager` can be injected, you don't need to pass it down to your `BreadCrumbs` component as a parameter (unless you are using the component for something other than URL paths). You can directly inject it into your `BreadCrumbs` component:

```html
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager;

<nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
    <ol class="breadcrumb">
```

- `@Body` isn't a component: it is a [`RenderFragment`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.renderfragment?view=aspnetcore-5.0).
- `@Body` doesn't have a path, per se; pages (designated with `@page`) do. Routing is managed by *App.razor* and configured in *Startup.cs*.

Comment: Thank you. NavigationManager helped a.k.a. did what I wanted. Only for others be careful, "NavigationManager.Uri.Substring(Navigator.BaseUri.Length)" will return you the path without "/" so instead of "/add/something/5" you will get it as "add/something/5" and if you comparing, you can get small trouble until figure it out.

Comment: Yes, I have a comment in my example about that. Remember to accept the answer you think best addresses your issue!

Answer (score 1):

You can get the current page URI from the `NavigationManager.Uri` property, by injecting `NavigationManager`. From that, you can extract your data.